# Node js MongoDb specific page view counter

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm making app with MEAN stack and I want on every get request to increase viewCounter on specific document ( Property ) inside collection. 
If i put this code inside get request of requested property

```
Property.findByIdAndUpdate('id', { $inc: { counter: 1 } }, {new: true})
```

It will increase loading of data and i want to do that after user gets his data.
So is the best way to do this just to send additional request to the database after initial data is loaded ?

```
Property {
   name: '',
   description: '',
   ...,
   viewCounter: 5
}

exports.getProperty = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {

    query = await Property.findById(req.params.id).lean();

    if(!query) {
      return next(new AppError('No property found with that ID', 404))
    }

    res.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        query
      }
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node events can be used to keep the counter of events.

[Official document](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html)

[Reference for code](https://softwareontheroad.com/ideal-nodejs-project-structure/#pubsub)

```
eventEmitter.on('db_view', ({ parameters }) => {
    eventTracker.track(
    'db_view',
    parameters
    );
})

eventEmitter.on('db_view', async ({ user, company }) => {
    Property.findByIdAndUpdate('id', { $inc: { counter: 1 } }, {new: true})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send request after making sure your document has loaded.

```js
angular.element($window).bind('load', function() {
    //put your code
});
```